# User getting created before custom user validator runs in Identity core

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

I am using identity core for user management in .net core 3.1 web api. Now, I want to check the users email for something and if it meets the requirement only then he will be created. The code below tells a lot about what I want to achieve

I have a custom user validator as below:

```
 public class CustomEmailValidator<TUser> : IUserValidator<TUser>
   where TUser : User
{

    public Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager,
                                              TUser user)
    {
        User userFromEmail = null;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Email))
            userFromEmail = manager.FindByEmailAsync(user.Email).Result;

        if (userFromEmail == null)
            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);

        return Task.FromResult(
        IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError
        {
            Code = "Err",
            Description = "You are already registered with us."
        }));
    }
}
```

I add the validator in my startup as below:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        IdentityBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>(opt =>
        {
            
            opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            opt.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789._-";
            opt.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            opt.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            opt.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            opt.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        })
        .AddUserValidator<CustomEmailValidator<User>>();
        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(Role), builder.Services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
        builder.AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<Role>>();
        builder.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>();
        builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>();
```

As can be seen, I want to use the default user validation and my custom validation too. The problem being the user gets created right after the default validation and the email always turns out as exists in my custom validation. I don't really want to override my default validations.

Creating the user as below:

```
    [HttpPost("Register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegister)
    {
        var userToCreate = _mapper.Map<User>(userForRegister);

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userForRegister.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var roleresult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userToCreate, "Member");
            return Ok(roleresult);
        }
        return BadRequest(result.Errors);
    }
```

**Note** This is not my actual use case. I know I can check for unique email in my default validation by making opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true. This is just to clear a concept for further development.

**Update** After further debugging, I see that the custom validation method is called twice. Once before user creation and once after creation for some reason. I insert a new unique email and the custom validation passes success and after user creation, custom validation is called again and find the email registered already and throws an error message. This is weird

Comment: How are you creating the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that AddToRoleAsync was calling the custom validator again and was finding the user present in the table. Had to include a check whether the user found in the table with the same email is the same as user getting getting updated.

Code below:

```
 public class CustomEmailValidator<TUser> : IUserValidator<TUser>
 where TUser : User
{

  public Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager,
                                          TUser user)
  {
    User userFromEmail = null;

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Email))
        userFromEmail = manager.FindByEmailAsync(user.Email).Result;

    if (userFromEmail == null)
        return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
    else {
            if(string.Equals(userFromEmail.Id, user.Id))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
            }
    }

    return Task.FromResult(
    IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError
    {
        Code = "Err",
        Description = "You are already registered with us."
    }));
  }
}
```

This should help a lot of people